# set of sequence and it limits in a Hausdorff space (not metric)Is closed?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I want to prove that for $K=\{x_n, n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\ell\}$ we have $\overline{K}\subset K$ in a Hausdorff topological space.

let $x\in \overline{K}$ that is. any open V such that $x\in V$: $V\cap A\neq \emptyset$

it means that there exists $y\in V\cap A$ , if $y=x$ we are done.

But if $x\neq y$, $V\setminus \{x\}$ is an open containing $y$.

Here I don't know how to continue?

Thanking you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x\notin K$; you want to prove that $x\notin\overline K$. Since $x\notin K$, $x\ne l$. Let $V_x$ and $V_l$ be neighborhoods of $x$ and of $l$ such that $V_x\cap V_l=\emptyset$. Since $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies x_n\in V_l$. So, $n\geqslant N\implies x_n\notin V_x$. For each $n\in\{1,2,\ldots,N-1\}$, let $V_n$ be a neighborhhod of $x$ such that $x_n\notin V_x$. Then $V_1\cap V_2\cap\ldots\cap V_{N-1}\cap V_x$ is a neighborhood of $x$ which contains no element of $K$. Therefore, $x\notin\overline K$.

Comment: Ah it is a good idea, but can I suppose instead of $V_1\cap V_2\cap\ldots\cap V_{p-1}\cap V_x$, $V_x\setminus\{x_{n_1},\ldots, x_{n_{p-1}}$ by choosing $V_x$ open ?

Comment: If you meant $V_x\setminus\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{N-1}\}$, then, yes, that is correct.

Comment: yes it is thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_n \to l$ in any space, $K:= \{x_n: n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{l\}$ is compact (easily seen by using the open cover definition: any open set containing $l$ already contains all but finitely many $x_n$ by convergence etc.)

In a Hausdorff space a compact subset is closed.